# This is the xml file going gray I created when I made the project on and off

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

This is the xml file going gray I created when I made the project on and off. And the parts where I use this layout give an error. This is the first time I've had anything like is. I have to rebuild it every time.

Error screenshot : [Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxpUz.png)

Comment: I still haven't solved the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what the problem is and share the error messages you get?

Comment: Like I said, I didn't get any error. 

I'm closing the project. When I reopen the xml file is grayed out as in the photo. This is what happens when I open the project directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I was accidentally right-click the file and I select "Mark as Plain Text".

Right-clicked again and clicked "Mark as XML", It's will solve problem.